# Create TikTok-Shop login signature

Tags: c#, tiktok

I'm currently synchronizing products between Shopee and Tiktok,

I'm doing the Tiktok login step, but when I go to the signature creation part, I get an error, on the manual page there are two ways to do it:

1. created with postman: https://bytedance.feishu.cn/docs/doccnZtvJej6U1AMEuIqz60IYuS

   I got an error in this part: https://prnt.sc/rLM9gJUB1fQD
2. create it manually: https://bytedance.feishu.cn/wiki/wikcnIa7kaSVY9no7LyR0FdYaxg#

   This way I code like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = "api/products/categories";
            var app_key = "572vgg";
            var access_token = "9d69P21WEhw-lSDY7suO6aFsZlhSWxDpqdtV-KOYltb_4mqBwcR1LsM3-PPUGfNP";
            var limit = 20;
            var timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            //var   timestamp=  GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
            var shop_id = 7076737409727136006;
            var category_id = 602362;            
            var secret = "9d04ea5bfcfb45947b1d0902d794077d2e59d08f";
            var signstring = secret + path + "app_key" + app_key + "category_id" + category_id + "limit" + limit + "shop_id" + shop_id + "timestamp" + timestamp + secret;

            var key = Convert.FromBase64String(secret);
            var provider = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(key);
            var hash = provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signstring));
            var sign =  prtByte2(hash);
 
            var url = "https://open-api.tiktokglobalshop.com/" + path+"?"+ "app_key="+ app_key + "&access_token="+ access_token+ "&sign="+ sign+ "&timestamp=" + timestamp+ "&category_id=" + category_id+ "&shop_id=" + shop_id;
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("value", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("key", "content-Type");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            
            MessageBox.Show(response.Content, "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

```
public static string prtByte2(byte[] b)
        {
            var e = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                e = e + b[i].ToString("x2");
            }
            return e;
        }
```

And also get the error:

> signature is invalid

Currently the token I get is as follows at postman:

[image: https://prnt.sc/i0-9GzGRtlO9]

I've been going back and forth for 3 days now and asked for support on Tiktok, but it still hasn't worked, looking forward to your help.

Please help me, I have tried my best.

Comment: Well the first thing you're going to do is regenerate you API secrets and investigate if you have a data breach.